# Adjust listView xml layout

Tags: android, xml, image, listview, layout

Good day guys. I seriously need someone help to adjust my `xml` layout. 
[image]

The above image shows the `ListView`, where it supposes to look like :

Image on the left, text on the right

```
Claims Type : Project
Amount      : 100
Description : Trainning
```

**xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Claimtype"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Claims Type : "
                android:maxLines="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Claimtype"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="Amount : "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Claimtype" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/amount"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Amount"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="Description : "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Amount" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Description"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this and let me know if some issue

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Claimtype"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Claims Type : "
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:text="dsjfhjh"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="Amount : "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/amount"
                android:text="dsjfhjsdkh" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="Description : "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Amount" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:text="jksdhfj"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Description"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you just need a LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And create String like:

```
Claims Type : "yourType" + "\n"
Amount      : 100 + "\n"
Description : Trainning + "\n"
```

to set for your TextView

Answer (score 1):

You can try that, i do it, fast so it's not really beautiful but it's what you want (i think). Try to not put solid value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Claimtype"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Claims Type : "
                android:maxLines="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Claimtype"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="Amount : "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Claimtype" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/amount"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Amount"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="Description : "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Amount" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Description"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance purposes, do not embed RelativeLayouts one into another. Since you only have two child in the parent RelativeLayout, you can use a LinearLayout instead.

Now regarding your issue :

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Amount"/>
```

`layout_toRightOf` means the TextView will be place at the right of the indicated View, only horizontally. You need to add a `layout_below` attribute also.

Answer (score 1):

try this, I have done it into my workspace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mytextview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCover"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgArrow"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgCover" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCoverHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlCT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgCover" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtDateTime"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Claims Type :"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtOutCT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtCT"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Project"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rlCT"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgCover" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtDateTime"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Amount :"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtOutAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtAmount"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="100"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlTraining"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rlAmount"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgCover" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTraining"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtDateTime"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Description :"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtOutTraining"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtTraining"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Trainning"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```